# recursively rename directories in bash

Tags: bash

I'd like to recursively rename all directories containing the string *foo* by replacing that part of the string with *Bar*.  I've got something like this so far, but it doesn't quite work.  I'd also like *foo* to be searched **case-insensitive**.

`find . -type d -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1//foo/Bar}"' -- {} \;`

Are there any elegant one-liners that might be better than this attempt?  I've actually tried a few but thought I'd defer to the experts.  Note: i'm doing this on a Mac OS X system, and don't have tools like **rename** installed.

Comment: If it is a one-timer it doesn't need to be a one-liner :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the following code using *parameter expansion*

```
find . -type d -iname '*foo*' -depth -exec bash -c '
    echo mv "$1" "${1//[Ff][Oo][Oo]/BAr}"
' -- {} \;
```

But your best bet will be using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895) (usable in any OS):

```
find . -type d -iname '*foo*' -depth -exec rename 's@Foo@Bar@gi' {} +
```

And if you are using `bash4` or `zsh` (`**` mean *recursive*):

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -n 's@Foo@Bar@gi' **/*foo*/
```

If it fit your needs, remove the `-n` (dry run) switch to rename for real.

**SOME DOC**

[rename](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epederst/rename/bin/rename.PL) was originally written by Perl's dad, Larry Wall himself.

Comment: @sputnick - [I'll happily upvote this if you remove the `sed` version.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)  :-)

Comment: Added `-depth ` to process the subdir first

Comment: I may have to look at installing `rename` for OS X.  I like that 2nd option but can't run it yet.

Comment: @Poe : `rename` is a simple `Perl` script, so you can using it without any install.

Comment: @Poe - Rename is indeed powerful.  And if you're already using macports or homebrew, using your package manager to manage software installs won't get you fired.

Comment: The glob was modified to match **only dirs** : `**/*foo*/` instead of `**/*foo*`

Comment: the `find -type d` command should be `find . -type d` since the path is missing but I knew what you meant.  I copied **rename** from my linux server to the OS X and it ran great.  Thanks!

Comment: oops, well it missed a subdirectory ex. `foo1/foo9` but other than that..., but I ran it again and it picked it up

Comment: @Poe : Which command line version ? I suspect bash4 one. If you have nested foo/foo/foo, I recommend `find . -type d -iname '*foo*' -depth -exec rename 's@Foo@Bar@gi' {} +
`

Comment: Adding `-d` to `rename` is necessary if `foo` occurs multiple places in the path otherwise you'll get `Can't rename X Y: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the problem is getting it to work with `mkdir -p foo/foo/foo`.

In this regard, I think a solution based on `find` will likely not work because the list of paths is probably predetermined.

The following is in no way *elegant*, and stretches the definition of a *one-liner*, but works for the above test.

```
$ mkdir -p foo/foo/foo

$ (shopt -s nullglob && _() { for P in "$1"*/; do Q="${P//[Ff][Oo][Oo]/bar}"; mv  -- "$P" "$Q"; _ "$Q"; done } && _ ./)

$ find
.
./bar
./bar/bar
./bar/bar/bar
```

Comment: **+1** - Excellent point. Arcane use of bash.  Nice work.  :)

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -type d -iname '*foo*' -exec bash -O nocasematch -c \
    '[[ $1 =~ (foo) ]] && mv "$1" "${1//${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/Bar}"' -- {} \;
```

**Pro:** Avoids sed.
**Con:** Will not find all matches if there are multiple in different cases.
**Con:** Is ridiculous.

Comment: OP needs a case insensitive substitution.

Comment: And `-name` will not match "*FOO*"

Comment: **+1** - Edited, this looks like it would work.  And yes, it's a little ridiculous.  :-)

Comment: You should add `-depth` switch ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Gilles Quenot and Wenli: The following worked for me. I based it on both of your solutions.

```
find . -depth -type d -name 'ReplaceMe*'  -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/ReplaceMe/ReplaceWith}"' -- {} \;
```

The `-execdir` seems to be key on linux Red hat 7.6

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching similar answers and this one worked:

```
find . -depth -name 'foo' -execdir bash -c 'mv "$0" ${0//foo/Bar}"' {} \;
```