# How to use a sed to change directory names recusively?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have to change the name of a bunch of directories.The rule is change every directory that contains hostnameABC for hostnameXYZ.

So, if its named hostnameABC_servers or Profiles_hostnameABC, it should be affected and changed for the names hostnameXYZ_servers and Profiles_hostnameABC. It has to be done recursively for each directory that maches this criteria inside /apps/XPTO/.

I was trying to use this pre made code. But doesn't work and since I don't know much about shell I can't fix it.

```
find /apps/XPTO/ -type d \
    | egrep -v "temp|bkp" \
    | egrep ".*hostnameABC[_a-Z0-9]*$" \
    | while read line; do
        mv "$line" `echo $line | sed "s/hostnameABC/hostnameXYZ/g"`
    done
```

It just changes nothing, can you help me to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141086/how-can-i-use-rename-to-recursively-rename-everyting-to-uppercase

Comment: You're really better off using `rename` here (the Perl one, which is available by default on Debian and Ubuntu, not the C one), which will be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recursively rename directories in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945987/recursively-rename-directories-in-bash)

Comment: give examples of paths that are not changed that you think should have been